# The point 2 is not a limit point of the set $[0,1)$ regardless of the topology on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The point 2 is not a limit point of the set $[0,1)$ regardless of the topology on $\mathbb R$.

Is this true or false? I think it is true because the limit point has to be a subset of the set and 2 is not.

Definition of limit point: Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space with $ A \subseteq X$. A point $x \in X$ is said to be a limit point of a provided that every open set containing $x$ contains a point $A$ different from $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Both the statement and your reasoning are false. A limit point of a subset $A \subseteq X$ does not have to lie in $A$. You even wrote the definition yourself ; it does not state that $x$ has to be in $A$. The condition can be reformulated as 
$$
\forall U \in \mathfrak T, \quad x \in U \quad \Rightarrow \quad A \cap U \neq \varnothing. 
$$
The key is that the condition $A \cap U \neq \varnothing$ "does not have to be caused by $x$", i.e. the intersection can contain a different point than $x$. So essentially, you can expect that if you "remove" a few open sets in your topology, then $2$ might become a limit point. Of course if you remove almost all of them then you have a better chance of finding a counter example. Try $\mathfrak T = \{ \varnothing, \mathbb R \}$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Consider the standard topology but with 1 and 2 trading places. 2 is a limit point in that topology.

And limit points do not need to be contained in the set of which they are a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Take the indiscrete topology $\mathfrak T = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The only open set containing $2$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which intersects $[0,1)$. Hence $2$ is a limit point of $[0,1)$ with respect to $\mathfrak T$.

Answer (score 0):

What about the topology where the only two open sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$.  Then every non-empty open set containing $2$ intersects that interval.